# NEMA 14 with integral JB -- how can I ground it to EMT?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, grounding

There are two general styles of NEMA 14 receptacle in wide use -- one is the conventionally yoked style that is used with a separate junction box in flush mount applications, but can also be used in a suitable surface-mount j-box:

[image: Leviton 278]

while the other is a surface-mount-only style that comes with a specially-fitted metal junction box with a non-standard hole pattern and conduit knockouts in the back and bottom:

[image: Leviton 55054]

In a case where the grounding conductor for the circuit is a conduit, the former type of receptacle can be grounded in any way possible for a regular duplex NEMA 5 -- either through the yoke if permitted by Code, or by way of a bonding jumper from the receptacle ground screw to the box.  However, the latter style of receptacle does not appear to have facilities in the box for a grounding jumper to be screwed to the box, and I am not sure if there is a "yoke" per se in that design that provides earthing continuity from the receptacle earth terminal to the box.  This leaves me with the question: short of pulling a redundant ground wire through the EMT, how can I ground an integral-box-type NEMA 14 to a run of EMT?  Or is the ground prong already set up to be electrically continuous to the backbox in such a receptacle design?

Comment: I can’t find a Leviton pdf that I remember from a few years ago, we had to prove as I remember.  As such, I’m 99% certain that the yoke of the recessed model and the metal backplate/bottomplate of the surface mount model are electrically connected to the ground pin internally.  We don’t stock anymore, it’s ordered per job only and I didn’t find one, new or used, in our shop to test with an ohm meter.  My recollection is that the recessed model requires a pigtail ground screw to box since the mount screw does not have a self-grounding clip.

Comment: BTW: leviton generally answers quick: https://www.leviton.com/en/support/contact-us/technical-support/corporate-technical-support-form